# How to get friends of friends with Redis

Tags: php, nosql, redis

I have list of all users friends in redis. (each user, One list for his friends)
Now how can I get the list of friends of friends for a user ?

Comment: can i use multiget command ?

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you can do it a better way. One idea is, fetch friends of a user and do the same for each friend(get their friends) and push them to an array by maintaining unique of each user.

```
$redis = new Predis\Client(array(
   'host' => '10.0.0.1',
   'port' =>  6379,
   'password' => {PASS_KEY}, 
   'database' => 0
));

$user = "key-to-user's-friends";
$userFriends = $redis->lrange($user, 0, -1);
$friendsOfFreinds = array();

foreach($userFriends as $friend){
$friendsFriends = $redis->lrange($friend, 0, -1);
foreach($friendsFriends as $friendFriend){
if(!in_array($friendFriend)){
$friendsOfFreinds[] = $friendFriend;
}
}
}
```

Comment: Can U please write an example Code for me ?

Comment: which php redis library are you using ?

Comment: predis ... php library

Comment: check the above, but its dumb way to do it. Try to find a better way

Answer (score 0):

This a more valid use case for neo4j. 
Try checking this out : http://www.neo4j.org/learn/graphdatabase